# Switching from Godaddy to AWS, switching DNS provider

Tags: amazon-web-services, web, dns

I'm working on transferring my website from godaddy, to AWS. I completed all the steps with the domain transfer, e.g. unlock domain, approve the transfer on both sides. And then I cancelled my Godaddy hosting. Now I have set up the AWS hosted zones, and I'm stuck on switching DNS services.

One of the steps is to enter the NS values on Route53 into the DNS provider on godaddy, but since I cancelled my hosting service I no longer have any way to access my DNS provider.

I'm wondering what to do in this situation. Is it possible to access the DNS provider directly? I waited for the TTL to expire before posting this because I thought that would fix my issues, but it did not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you transferred the domain registration to Route 53, you are following a set of instructions that doesn't match what you are trying to accomplish.

In Route 53...

Under "Hosted Zones," select your domain.  Make a note of the 4 name servers assigned.

Then, under "Registered Domains," select your domain.

The name servers shown here need to match the 4 name servers that were assigned to your Hosted Zone.

Click Add/Edit Name Servers to modify them.  They are probably still pointing to the Go Daddy (something like "nsxx.domaincontrol.com" if I remember correctly) name servers.

It sounds like what you were reading was instructions for moving your DNS *hosting* to Route 53, without doing a domain transfer, which is change of the registrar of record.  Changing DNS hosting, only, would not have involved unlocking and approving as you described.  Registrar and hosting are two completely separate services, but providers often bundle them together, leaving users often unaware of the distinction.